# LocationManager generating errorin code

Tags: android

this is my code in android and is showing error. I dont know what is wrong but i am certaqin it has to do something with `LocationManager` because until that line it works fine.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Log.d("Exception", "Something gone wrong !! ");

/*after this line it shows error */

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

All i want right now is to display value of longitude and latitude so that i can be sure code is good till here.

Comment: what error in logcat.. and u r using device or emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Declate this variable**

```
 Location loc;
```

**Write this code in Oncreate() method**

```
LocationManager mlocManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

**Then Write**

```
loc.getLatitude();
loc.getLongitude();
```

**Now you can use the value of latitude and longitude...  :-)**

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Code Snippet**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
  LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
  mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}

/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {

    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

    String Text = "My current location is: " +
    "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
    "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
  {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
  {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
  {

  }
}
```

**Check Below Line in Manifest file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: This will Fetch Coordinates every time my GPS Coordinates are changed. but I want The Value of the coordinates at the time of initialization of the App. can that be Done ?

Comment: yes store the value of your coordinates into a variable when the application launch.